# Learning Latex from the scratch

Tags: learning

What are the some great sources from where I can systematically learn latex. My main area of interest are **document class beamer** and **document class exam**.

I have enrolled in one of the online courses provided by edx : https://www.edx.org/course/latex-for-students-engineers-and-scientists-2 but it covers basic concepts and for which it is very good but where should I head after this course. Could someone suggest some great resources or youtube playlists for this purpose.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/35864 has a great list of options. I doubt that many resources will focus a lot on the `exam` class.

Comment: @moewe  but [examdoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) (137 pages) is plenty focused in this class.

Comment: @Fran Well, yeah, you'd expect the documentation would focus on the class. I was trying to say that I expect there to be little third-party (non documentation/manual) resources on it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best resources to learn latex are latex wikibook ( https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX ) and The LaTeX companion by Mittelbach F., Goossens M , there is also an app for android